# La linea escrita es demasiado larga - CMD

Tags: windows, consola, cmd

Intento hacer el siguiente comando en CMD para guardar %PATH% con saltos de linea en un fichero de texto.

```
"@echo. %PATH:;= & @echo.%" > path.txt
```

Con esto intento hacerlo con saltos de linea para luego poder hacer un findstr desde ese fichero. Pero me da error de La linea escrita es demasiado larga.
Y lo mismo si intento mandarla a traves de un pipe a otro comando como findstr en vez de al archivo. Estoy haciendo algo mal?
Pensaba que para agrupar comandos eran las comillas pero igual no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un poco retorcido y oscuro, pero este `pathnl.bat` creo que hace lo que buscas

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "token=!PATH!"
echo !token:;=^

!
```

Explicación [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877969/replace-string-with-a-new-line-in-batch).

Comment: Esta bien. No hay ninguna solucion que pueda usar dentro de la propia linea de comandos? Es un poco limitante esto.